# Why won't a fraction print in an array that holds doubles

Tags: arrays, printf, double

When I use this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    double array[1][1];
    array[0][0]=3/10;
    printf("%lf",array[0][0]);
}
```

And print instead of giving me a 0.30000 I get a 0.000000
Why?

Answer (score 2):

The expression `3/10` is calculated using *integer division* because both operands are integers. Instead, use `3.0/10.0` to be sure the calculation is done using floating point.